# How to display image in a pdf using barryvdh/laravel-dompdf?

Tags: dompdf, laravel-10

I'm new to Laravel, and it's already taking me 6 hours figuring this out. I am using a form to fetch data and trying to print it as a PDF. The data works, yet the image didn't work. In my development server, it works, but it doesn't work when I host my app.

Here's my code to load the image on the blade file for the PDF template.

```
<img src="public/img/logo.png">
```

heres my controller to print it

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.pdf', $datas)
return $pdf->stream('pdf.pdf');
```

Comment: fyi, the `public/` folder should never appear in any url, it should be the server's "DocumentRoot"